# Angular 2 Error HTTPResponse not found

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Estou tentando implementar uma tela de login que acessa uma api através de um servidor, eu preciso passar o email e a senha do usuário para a api, e ela me retorna NULL em caso de erro ou um number em caso de sucesso (id do usuário).

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem ao clicar no botão de submit:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found",url: "https://dev.endereco/login/undefined", ok: false, …}
```

Também recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
POST https://dev.endereco/login/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Segue partes importantes do meu código:

**login.component.html:**

```
<input type="text" required name="email" [(ngModel)]="usuario.email" #nome="ngModel" id="usuario" placeholder="Email">

<input type="password" required name="password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" #senha="ngModel" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">

<button type="submit" name="entrar" (click)="fazerLogin(usuario.email, usuario.password)" class="login" id="login-button">Entrar</button>
```

**login.component.ts:**

```
private usuario: Usuario = new Usuario(); //Usuario é meu tipo de dado, foi declarado uma interface que possui o email e o password.

 public idUsuario: any = null;

 public alertaUsuarioIncorreto: boolean = false;

 constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) { }

  fazerLogin(usuario: Usuario): void{
    this.authService.fazerLogin(usuario.email, usuario.password)
      .subscribe(user => this.idUsuario = user);

      if(this.idUsuario != null){ //se for diferente de null faz login
        this.alertaUsuarioIncorreto = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/home'])
      }else{ //caso contrario mostra um toast com msg de erro
        this.alertaUsuarioIncorreto = true;
        var x = document.getElementById("toast")
        x.className = "show";
        setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 5000);
      }
    }
}
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<Usuario>  {
    return this._http.post<Usuario>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+email,password)
  }
```

@Edit:

Tentei adicionar um cabeçalho fornecido pelo Angular (?):

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

passando o cabeçalho como parâmetro da função:

```
 fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<Usuario>  {
    return this._http.post<Usuario>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+email,password, httpOptions)
      }
```

Agora recebo:

```
: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

Comment: A sua função fazerLogin do componente recebe so um parâmetro e vc esta passando dois.

Comment: Eduardo, a função fazer login recebe um tipo de dados Usuario que contém o nome de usuario e a senha. Acredito que o problema não seja esse

Comment: Receber dois parâmetros e diferente de receber um parâmetro objeto com duas propriedades. Tenta (click)="fazerLogin(usuario)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Eduardo Vargas mencionou nos comentários, seu `login.component.html` passa dois parâmetros para a função `fazerLogin, sendo que a mesma só recebe um. Podemos notar que ele não está interpretando o valor passado se analisarmos a url gerada:

```
https://dev.endereco/login/UNDEFINED
```

Para resolver o problema, basta passar o objeto completo como paramêtro:

```
(click)="fazerLogin(usuario)"
```

Fazendo assim, seu componente recebe o usuário completo, com todas as propriedades.